# Changing the eval method into something safer?

Tags: javascript

I got a task to create a calculator and my mentor told me to change the eval to a safer method.

I tried doing it with a function, but he said that this is not a way to go any suggestions?
(The new Function part is where I am stuck at)

```
calculate = () => {
     let expression = document.getElementById('display').value;
    try {
        let result = new Function('return ' + expression)();
        document.getElementById('display').value = result;
    } catch (error) {
        document.getElementById('display').value = 'Error';
    }
};
```

What I don't want to happen is when a user types 033 * 33 it wouldn't be valid (the 0 at the front).